# Why this database update does nothing only in one client pc and works fine on several others?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, validation, sql-update

I have a desktop project saving data into a SQL Server database using this code:

```
         this.Validate();

         this.PropostasCabBindingSource.EndEdit();

         this.PropostasLinhasBindingSource.EndEdit();

         this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(DBEmpresa);
```

It works fine on several clients except one. On that client it gives no exception but don't make any changes on the database table (`PropostasCab`). That client has the same .NET (v4.6.2), the same SQL Server version (v12.0.2569), same SQL Server 2005 backward compatibility as the other clients on the network.

I tried to restart the services I mentioned, reinstall SQL Server 2005 backward compatibility and nothing.

Any ideas? Some SQL Server conflict?

Comment: Why are you still using SQL Server 2005? It hasn't received any support for almost 5 years.

Comment: I don't use SQL Server 2005. I am using SQl Server 2014. The machines have MS SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility installed (I don't know exactly why, other software (SAGE) installed it)

Comment: From ask.sage.co.uk:

"Attempting to take a backup without the SQL Backward Compatibility Components installed on the client machine may give the following error: 'The SQL Server is not available on the network. Please consult your network administrator.' "

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

That specific pc had Region Format as 'us-US' instead of 'pt-PT'.
So the database was rolling back because of some currencies formated as 'us-US'

Now i changed the CultureInfo:

```
 CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

and works fine.

Thanks.